# How to select all row in mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

Below are the code for connection of mongodb

I am tring the fetch all row:

```
<?php
        echo '<pre>';

        $m = new MongoClient();
        $dbname = $m->selectDB('module1');
        echo '<br> connection var dump';
        var_dump($m);
        $collection = $dbname->selectCollection('collection');
        $posts = $dbname->posts;

        echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

to find all rows just dont provide any thing to find() method that will return all rows

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php)

```
<?php


        $m = new MongoClient();
        $dbname = $m->selectDB('module1');
        echo '<br> connection var dump';
        var_dump($m);
        $collection = $dbname->selectCollection('collection');
        $posts = $collection->find();   ?>
```

you can preety print them as

```
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($posts,true).'</pre>';
```

or

```
 foreach ($posts as $doc) {
          var_dump($doc);
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

[db.collection.find()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)  method with no parameters returns all documents from a collection and returns all fields for the documents. So just invoke `$collection->find()`